# Find $x+y+z$, where $x, y, z$ are edges of a parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, ratio, arithmetic-progressions, solid-geometry

A parallelepiped has its edges represented by $x$, $y$ and $z$, these are directly proportional to the numbers $3$, $4$ and $5$ respectively. It is also known that they are, in this order, in increasing arithmetic progression. The diagonal of this parallelepiped measures $10\sqrt{2}$. Then the sum $x+y+z$ is equal to?

**Comments:**

By hypothesis we have $x = 3m$, $y = 4n$ and $z = 5k$. I'm tried to write $(x,y,z) = (y - r, y , y+r)$ where $r$ is a reason of the arithmetic progression, then $x + y + z = 3y$. Moreover, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = 10\sqrt{2}$ and from this equality we have an equation in two of the variables.
I am not able to fit the facts and find the value of one of the variables to find the others.

Comment: Something is wrong : i think we have $x:y:z = 3:4:5$, so that $x=3k,y=4k$ and $z=5k$ for some $k$ , rather than what you've written.

Comment: "By hypothesis we have x=3m, y=4n and z=5k."  That's *ALWAYS* true (just let $m = \frac x; n=\frac y4$ etc.)  Our hypothesis is that they are proportional *by the same proportion* to $3:4:5$.  so $x = 3m$ and $y = 4m$ and $z = 5m$ for the *same* value of $m$.  So you have $x+y+z= 3m + 4m + 5m = 12m$.  And you have them in arithmetic progression so you  have $x+y+z=3y = 12m$ ... dang ... I was hoping that be enough numbers can only be in arithmetic progression if the propotions are.  Have to use the diagonal formula for parallelepid... too bad I've completely forgotten what a parallelepid is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=3m,$ $y=4m$ and $z=5m$ so
$$9m^2+16m^2+25m^2=200,$$ which gives $$m=2.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: I am not understanding why the proportionality constant is the same for the three numbers. For in no time doing so I use that they are in arithmetic progression.

Comment: @Croos  By the given $x:y:z=3:4:5,$ which says that if $x=3m$ so $y=4m$ and $z=5m$. Since $3m+5m=2\cdot 4m,$ we see that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Thank you your help.

Comment: "I am not understanding why the proportionality constant is the same for the three numbers." thats what being proportional *means*.  If the proportional constant wasn't the same then it wouldn't be a constant and the statement 'they are proportional" would be meaning less.... Example: $27=3k;k=9$ and $39=4m;m=\frac {39}4$ and $38=5n;n=\frac {38}5$ but it'd be *meaningless* to so $27:39:38$ are ins $3:4:5$ proportion.

Comment: This information that they are in arithmetic progression is unnecessary in the statement, correct? This is only a consequence.

Comment: @Croos   Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

$$×=3k,y=4k,z=5k$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=9k^2+16k^2+25k^2=200$$
$$50k^2=200, k^2=4, k=2, k\not=-2$$
$$×=6,y=8, z=10$$

Comment: Thank you your help.